# Rendering tweets on the server side

Tags: javascript, twitter

Is there a library that would take the API response and render tweets server-side in accordance with [twitter ddr](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements)?

I'm concerned that I'm reinventing the wheel when processing [tweet entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities), parsing the timestamp and rendering author name/avatar/@username. Twitter's `widget.js` seems to be very client side focused as-is; I haven't found the script's version that's documented and licensed for modified use on the server.

I'd rather avoid rendering on the client when it could be be pre-rendered and cached - just showing the latest tweet from a given account.

Comment: What server and language are you using?

Comment: @DanRoss: server side javascript hence the tag; it's actually not `node` though, scripts are SpiderMonkey-interpreted on the server. Yup.

Comment: I had to google that one, but there are some big projects using spidermonkey, including CouchDB. I guess you aren't crazy :)

Comment: How about this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Comment: @CodeGroover: good links, but what really did it for me is [twitter-text-js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js) from [mef's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18757718/1081234) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js), it can be used at server side (as a node.js package), you probably can use it.

Comment: [Seems legit](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/twitter-text-library-and-tco-links-wrapping-update), worth mentioning it's also available for [ruby](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb) and [java](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java).